# Woocommerce изменение переменной

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Написал плагин, рассчитывающий цену на доставку товара.
Не смог понять как добавлять цену доставки к основной цене товара Woocommerce.
Т.е. я сделал товар "Книга" с ценой 100р.
На сайте я добавляю товар в корзину.
В корзине: интерфейс плагина доставки и ниже Woocommerce c ценой товара 100р.
Как мне добавить к этой сумме сумму доставки?

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'My_func');
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_func',10,2);
add_action('woocommerce_shipping_init', 'my_func');
add_action('woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'action_woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 10, 2);
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'my_func');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо использовать $woocommerce->cart->add_fee():

```
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $shipping_fee   = 10;

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Доставка', $shipping_fee, true, '' );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
```

Comment: if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return; - не совсем понял эту строку.
Функция отрабатывает только в админке?  
Вставлял эту функцию - не помогло(

Comment: У меня на тестовом сайте работает. Зайдите сюда: http://test.kagg.eu/product/%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC-%E2%84%961/, добавьте его в корзину (не все товары на тестовом сайте можно добавить в корзину). Перейдите в корзину, увидите стоимость доставки. ///// Насчет if - там же ДВА условия: если в админке и при этом не в ajax, то ничего не делаем. Не обращайте на это внимания, так надо, это из примеров WooCommerce.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Можно еще 1 вопрос. http://www.mint-studio.net/web-development/wordpress/add-new-method-delivery-woocommerce.html по этой странице туториал о добавлении свое доставки. Новый метод в настройках woocommerce появился. Однако в зонах только 3 стандартных. Выбираю ли Россию или весь мир.

Comment: Создайте, пожалуйста, другой вопрос.